# Changing the value of a Pandas DataFrame datapoint

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I would like to change the value of a `Pandas` DataFrame based on index and column. I am getting an error `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`. I searched around and found similar questions/answers, but none that I was able to apply.

```
import pandas as pd

BabyDataSet = [('Bob', 968), ('Jessica', 155), ('Mary', 77), ('John', 578), ('Mel', 973)]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a','b','c','d','e'], data=BabyDataSet, columns=['Names', 'Births'])
df.ix['c']['Births'] = 10
print df
```

Comment: I think you are getting a warning which points you to here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong it should be this:

```
In [30]:
df.ix['c','Births'] = 10 
df

Out[30]:
     Names  Births
a      Bob     968
b  Jessica     155
c     Mary      10
d     John     578
e      Mel     973
```

The first component is the index label and the second is the column name.

You could also do

```
In [32]:
df.loc['c','Births'] = 10 
df

Out[32]:
     Names  Births
a      Bob     968
b  Jessica     155
c     Mary      10
d     John     578
e      Mel     973
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    # duckdb
    df.reset_index().sql().select("names,case when index='c' then 10 else Births end Births")

out

┌─────────┬────────┐
│  Names  │ Births │
│ varchar │ int64  │
├─────────┼────────┤
│ Bob     │    968 │
│ Jessica │    155 │
│ Mary    │     10 │
│ John    │    578 │
│ Mel     │    973 │
```